# Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':core:classpath' after it has been resolved. Gradle configure on demand problem

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with 1 app module (MyApplication) and 1 library module (core).
When I'm trying to see 'gradlew MyApplication:dependencies',
i'm having an error

```
* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':core'.
> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':core:classpath' after it has been resolved.
```

In top-level directory I have build.gradle with this:

```
   ...
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
   ...
```

and also I set

> org.gradle.configureondemand=true

In MyApplication directory I have build.gradle with typical application configuration

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
...
```

In core directory I have build.gradle with this:

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}
...
```

Please ask if additional information from gradle files is needed.

I'm sorry it's project have limitations on disclosure of source code and whole gradle files body.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I understood what's coming wrong.
In top-folder build.gradle we already defined stuff related to android build tools:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
```

So we need to delete this definition from application or library modules:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"

apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

ext.getArtifactId = {
    return "core"
}

if(project.hasProperty("PATH_SET_VERSION") == true){
    apply from: project.property("PATH_SET_VERSION").toString()
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "our local repositiry"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' // it's not needed here, so better to delete this dependencies {...} section
    }
}
```

Comment: I move sub-module classpath to top gradle file then it gets fixed.